# При работе с датами на JS возникают ошибки

Tags: javascript

date1 присваиваю текущее время. Потом date2 присваиваю date1 и добавляю 1 год, почему date1 при этом тоже увеличивается на 1 год? Связано ли это с тем, что обеим переменным присваивается одна и та же ссылка на new Date() и любые манипуляции будут менять дату в одном и том же месте.

Как это обойти, если нужно допустим организовать период с интервалом в 1 год?

```js
var date1 = new Date();
console.log('Дата 1', date1);
var date2 = date1
console.log('Дата 2', date2)

date2.setFullYear(Number(date2.getFullYear() + 1));
console.log('Дата 2 после прибавления 1 года', date2)
console.log('Дата 1 ', date1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, связано с этим.

```js
var date1 = new Date();
console.log('Дата 1', date1);
var date2 = new Date(date1); // !!!
console.log('Дата 2', date2);

date2.setFullYear(Number(date2.getFullYear() + 1));
console.log('Дата 2 после прибавления 1 года', date2);
console.log('Дата 1 ', date1);
```